# Show that the series converges uniformly

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^2$ converges uniformly on $[a,-a]$  , $a\in \mathbb{R}$.**

My attempt:

Using Taylor's formula, we have:$$ \sin\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^2 = \dfrac{x^2}{n^2} + o\left( \dfrac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$

Therefore, 
$$\sin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{n^2}\right) \leq \dfrac{x^2}{n^2} \leq \dfrac{a^2}{n^2}$$

We then have $\| \sin\dfrac{x^2}{n^2}\| \leq \dfrac{a^2}{n^2} \leq \infty$

Therefore, according to Weierstrass's criteria:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^2$   converges uniformly on $[a,-a]$

**Is that the right approach to the problem?**

Comment: I assume you mean "Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin (\dfrac{x}{n})^2$ converges uniformly on $[-a, a]$". If that's wrong, then I will roll back my edit.

Comment: You're on the right way, you should just bound $\omicron(x^2/n^2)$ by some constant time $x^2/n^2$ instead of $0$. But you're actually allmost done.

Comment: it's not a 0, $\omicron$ is a function that tends extremely rapidly to 0

Comment: $\sin x \leq \lvert x\rvert$ holds in general, no need for Taylor here (which would require to handle the $o()$ term separately, or at least mention it). In your argument, though, you seem to have magically put the squares inside the $\sin$ for no reason? (For this last point: I am reading the general term as $(\sin(x/n))^2$, you seem to read it as $\sin((x/n)^2)$).

Comment: Reminder: We need $|\sin(x^2/n^2)| \le x^2/n^2,$ not just $\sin(x^2/n^2) \le x^2/n^2$

Comment: @zhw. for large $n$ and bounded $x$ this holds.

Comment: @Yongyong Yes I know, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: @zhw. aha, ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your $x$ is bounded, there exists an $N$ such that 
\begin{equation}
0<\frac{x^2}{n^2}\leq \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}
for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in[-a,a]$. Now you can use the inequality $0\leq \sin x\leq x $ for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.